# Transparency image on opaque image in ImageView

Tags: android

i need a transparent image lying on opaque image.Below is the code that i have in xml.

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/next"
    android:id="@+id/imageview1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:alpha="0.3" />
```

Is this right method to follow?

Comment: at first set `android:alpha="0.5"` instead `0.3`

Answer (score 0):

yes if both are inside same `RelativeLayout`. note you have width and height set differently (both should have same for width and height). you may also remove `layout_alignParentStart` from both (or even optionally remove all `align_` related params when `match_parent`)

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageview1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:alpha="0.3" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

there is also suspicious line in first `ImageView`:

```
android:layout_above="@+id/next"
```

what is `next`? it should be set probably for `RealtiveLayout`, which should be inside another `RelativeLayout`, which contains `next` View

Comment: next is the id of button

Comment: Even though i removed the all align elements it is not working why?

Comment: without code its just guessing... post your whole XML

Comment: you've edited my answer instead your question... put this code in your question and add some Java code how (and what) you are setting drawable for these `ImageView`s. In your edit fo my ans I still see different sizes for both `ImageView`s, one have both dimens `match_parent`, second one have `wrap_content` (and no content set by XML, so it will be 0x0 size). First of all: set both to `match_parent`. Note that `alpha` attribute was introduced in Android 3.0 (API15), in earlier OS versions it is simply not respected at all